# Display unique number with Fix letter

Tags: php, jquery

Is possible to display unique number with starting Fix letter using PHP or JQ.

Example : S595466232

(i.e. : S + 10 random & unique number.)

Comment: Generate a unique number, concatenate it with a letter prefix (e.g. `echo 'S' . mt_rand(1000,9999);` in PHP).... though you'll have to take extra steps to ensure that the number is unique by checking it against existing numbers

Answer (score -1):

You can use rand function in php.

```
echo 'S' . rand(1000000000,9999999999);
```

Comment: The solution doesn't provide a required uniqueness of a generated number.

Comment: yeah it generate random S+10 number but how to verify weather it is unique or not? @Mark

Comment: Uniqueness can be defined in a group, a dataset etc. You should check it in where you use the value. You can save values into a database or a file and then check them. If you provide more information about your need, I can help more.